# how to use Django F() expression in `update` for JSONField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have around 12 million records that I need to update in my postgres db (so I need to do it in an efficient way).
I am using Django.

I have to update a jsonfield column (`extra_info`) to use values from a different column (`related_type_id` which is an integer) in the same model.

Trying to do it with an `update`. This seems to be the way to do it most efficiently.
Example:

```
Person.objects.all().update(extra_info={
  "type": "Human",
  "id": F('related_type_id')
})
```

This errors out with : "Object of type F is not JSON serializable".
I thought the F() will give back the value of that column (which should be an integer) which should be serializable.
Can this be done ? Or am I trying to do it in the wrong way.
I don't really want to iterate in a for loop and update each record with a `save()` because it will take too long. There's too many records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django database function [JSONObject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#jsonobject) should work, it returns a valid JSON object from key-value pairs and may be passed `F` objects

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import JSONObject

Person.objects.all().update(extra_info=JSONObject(
  type=Value('Human'),
  id=F('related_type_id')
))
```

Comment: wow Nice, this seems to work for the F() part ! Any idea why i'm getting "Cannot resolve keyword "Human" into field. Choice are: <here it lists the available columns in the mode>"
That seems like a weird error , why is it treating "Human" as a keyword. I also tried changing `type` to `custom_type` but same error (i wanted to see if "type" is somehow reserved but it makes no difference).

Comment: @sco Using `Value` should work, updated https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions. If you just pass a string it seems to use the value of the column, you might not need to use the `F` object just the string `'related_type_id'`